# Can we connect ms sql server using direct jdbc driver without jtds driver in Android studio

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc

```
private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;

public void connect() {
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://YOUR_SERVER:YOUR_PORT;databaseName=YOUR_DATABASE;user=YOUR_USERNAME;password=YOUR_PASSWORD;";
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Not able to connect ms sql server using latest JDBC driver in Android studio

I try to connect with jtds driver it get connected but i want to connect with latest JDBC driver and Jtds have old version of JDBC i tried with  latest JDBC but it Won't get connected it throws exception

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you failed to include any code, failed to include the exception, failed to specify the exact version numbers, failed to clarify what you mean by a direct jdbc driver, and you already have some version of all the above that works (but you didn't include that either).

Comment: Please read up on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions which will receive good answers.

Comment: please include error log message

Comment: Voting to close (even after it was reopened) because you have still not included any details of the exception, or any of the other details requested in the above messages. We can't answer this question without more information. A stack trace would be useful too.